# Why my python mechanize script cannot work for this specific site

Tags: python, forms, search, mechanize

I need to simulate the process of inputting an item name and clicking the search button on http://ccclub.cmbchina.com/ccclubnew/.

if I inspect directly in HTML, the search form is described with name "searchKey"

```
<span class="searchinput">
     <input type="text" name="searchKey" id="searchKey" maxlength="25">
</span>
```

here below is the script:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# Want debugging messages?
br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_debug_redirects(True)
br.set_debug_responses(True)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

br.open("http://ccclub.cmbchina.com/ccclubnew/")
```

I get

```
br.select_form('searchKey')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 524, in select_form
    raise FormNotFoundError("no form matching "+description)
FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'searchKey'
```

and the br.forms() is empty.

my question is: why mechanize cannot select the form which exists in html? what's the possible solution to handle this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `input` with name searchKey itself is no form. A form comes with the [`<form>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) tag, but honestly, this searchbox appears not to be part of a form; you'll have to simulate setting the text of the input and pressing it.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you specify how to setting the text of the input, if mechanize is not the case for such scene, what's the potential tool to dig?

Answer (score 1):

How about using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [BeatifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

Comment: this. it also helps when both are installed

Comment: I checked quickly beautiful soup, and didn't see any interactive features. it sounds like the major usage of soup is parsering the page.